# Magento CE 1.8 zoom function in Products.js from Product.Zoom is causing problems with scaling (missing statement)

Tags: javascript, magento, prototypejs, zooming, magento-1.8

In the new version of Magento CE 1.8 there is a problem with the zoom function in that it only scales the height, and not the width.  Scaling worked before this. I chased it down to the template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml file where there is a call to Product.Zoom on the image in Products.js.

Well I after hours of debugging I found the solution to this problem.  When looking at older versions of magento, I compared the Products.js file and it seems that in the Product.Zoom.prototype function the line "this.containerDim.ratio = this.containerDim.width/this.containerDim.height" was deleted from the new version of 1.8.  Its missing.

Once I added that line, it worked again.  I decided to post this question in case anyone wants to fix it fast in the future.  Thanks.